# how to add System.Windows.Data reference for dotnet of mac

Tags: c#, .net, macos, .net-core

I am developing dotnet console application in my mac. I have installed dotnet SDK. And I have finished some console application. But when I try to add the reference by `using System.Windows.Data;`， the build output is:

```
The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

It seems that System.Window.Data is not in. But I don't know to add reference of this. I have tried `dotnet add package System.Window.Data`. Failed still.
I think this should be a built-in reference. But I am not sure if it caused by Mac.

Comment: Why do you want to use from System.Windows.Data? If you intend to create UI application, consider using [AvaloniaUI](https://avaloniaui.net/) it's crossplatform and available on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS Visual Studio:

Right click on the Project
Select "Add Reference..."
Navigate to the ".NET" tab
Find "System.Windows.Data" and select it
Click OK.

Comment: I have pressed that I am using mac. If I use windows, I would not ask this question.

Comment: OK,  can you check this DLL is available in GAC, if not available you need to download and register it in GAC

Answer (score 0):

This DLC is related to WPF and maybe also to Forms. It is not supported in .Net Core libraries.  If you define it is a WPF class library or WPF program, you can just add the using statement and it should work.